# Which word is “they” referring to?

Tags: meaning

> That’s just our minds doing the job **they** were designed to do: trying
>   to anticipate and solve problems and avoid potential pitfalls.

Which word is “they” referring to? Our minds or "thoughts and feelings
that include criticism, doubt, and fear"(which is mentioned in the previous sentence)?

Also I can't get the point. So, Could you please explain the sentence to me?

The fuller text is:

> The prevailing wisdom says that difficult thoughts and feelings have
>   no place at the office: Executives, and particularly leaders, should
>   be either stoic or cheerful; they must project confidence and damp
>   down any negativity bubbling up inside them. But that goes against
>   basic biology. All healthy human beings have an inner stream of
>   thoughts and feelings that include criticism, doubt, and fear. That’s
>   just our minds doing the job **they** were designed to do: trying to
>   anticipate and solve problems and avoid potential pitfalls.

https://hbr.org/2013/11/emotional-agility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They** is referring to our minds. The sentence means that:

> all healthy human beings have an inner stream of thoughts and feelings that include criticism and this is just what our minds were meant to do/

Answer (score 1):

As a purely standalone sentence, the only thing that **they** can be referring to is **our minds** because there is nothing else in the sentence that comes before it that's plural: *they* can't be referencing *that* nor can it be referencing *the job* because both of those things are singular:

> That’s just **our minds** doing the job **they** were designed to do . . .

---

However, with more context, the use of *they* in exactly the same sentence could refer to something else.

For example, consider this fictional context:

> We developed telekinesis and were able to move those objects around that we'd **designed** ***robots*** for in the past. That's just our minds doing the job ***they*** **were designed** to do.

Here, it's more likely that *they* doesn't actually refer to *our minds* but to *our robots* instead. (Because of the specific correlation of *designed*.)

---

This just highlights that context can be very important—and that exactly the same sentence can mean something different when it comes after something else.

In your particular passage, however, there is nothing that makes a different interpretation more likely than the original: *they* is still almost certainly referring to *our minds*.

---

Note that in the previous sentence this is the noun you were questioning:

> **an inner stream** of thoughts and feelings that include criticism, doubt, and fear

The actual noun is singular, not plural. Although *they* could be used mistakenly to refer to it, if we assume that it is being used correctly, then it is not. Otherwise the pronoun used would be *it*.

> That’s just our minds doing the job **this inner stream** of thoughts and feelings **was** designed to do . . .

Or:

> That’s just our minds doing the job **it was** designed to do . . .

Comment: I'd say even in your contrived example, "they" is ambiguous at best, and most people would still assume it referred to "minds" because it's the most recent candidate.